# What's the best way to retrieve two pieces of data from an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I've got an XML document that is in either a pre or post FO transformed state that I need to extract some information from.  In the pre-case, I need to pull out two tags that represent the pageWidth and pageHeight and in the post case I need to extract the page-height and page-width parameters from a specific tag (I forget which one it is off the top of my head).

What I'm looking for is an efficient/easily maintainable way to grab these two elements.  I'd like to only read the document a single time fetching the two things I need.

I initially started writing something that would use `BufferedReader` + `FileReader`, but then I'm doing string searching and it gets messy when the tags span multiple lines.  I then looked at the `DOMParser`, which seems like it would be ideal, but I don't want to have to read the entire file into memory if I could help it as the files could potentially be large and the tags I'm looking for will nearly always be close to the top of the file.  I then looked into `SAXParser`, but that seems like a big pile of complicated overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Anybody have any advice? Or simple implementations that would accomplish my goal?  Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to mention that due to various limitations I have, whatever I use has to be "builtin" to core Java, in which I can't use and/or download any 3rd party XML tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While XPath is very good for querying XML data, I am not aware of good and fast XPath implementation for Java (they all use DOM model at least).

I would recommend you to stick with StAX. It is extremely fast even for huge files, and it's cursor API is rather trivial:

```
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader r = f.createXMLStreamReader("my.xml");
try {
  while (r.hasNext()) {
    r.next();
    . . .
  }
} finally {
  r.close()
}
```

Consult [StAX tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html) and [XMLStreamReader javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) for more information.

Comment: That seems to be almost exactly what I was looking for. Going to investigate further.

Comment: This worked perfectly according to what I wanted it to do. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Morinar - I'd suggest upvoting, in addition to accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XPath](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) to search for your tags. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) is a tutorial on forming XPath expressions. And [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html) is an article on using XPath with Java.

---

An easy to use parser (dom, sax) is [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/). It would be quite easier to use than the built-in SAXParser.

Answer (score 0):

try ["XMLDog"](http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/XMLDog)

This uses sax to evaluate xpaths